# jQuery div puzzle

Tags: jquery, html

I have three column on site. Each column has divs with info (about 20-30 in column. Id named as left-a..z, center-a..z, right-a..z). I need to hide some not imortant divs from center and right column, and some divs from left column put to center or right column.

I solve this question by this way:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dimaomni/SThaQ/2/)

```
$(function(){
    $("#wrapper > #right1").fadeOut(1000).attr('id','right1-chg');
    $("#wrapper > #left-name").fadeOut(1000).attr('id','right1');
    $("#wrapper > #right1").fadeIn(1000);

    $("#wrapper > #right2").fadeOut(1000).attr('id','right2-chg');;
    $("#wrapper > #left-surname").attr('id','right2');
});

$(function(){
    $(".click").click(function(){
    $("#wrapper > #right1").attr('id','left-name');
    $("#wrapper > #right1-chg").attr('id','right1').fadeIn(3000);
    $("#wrapper > #left-name").fadeIn(1000);

    $("#wrapper > #right2").attr('id','left-surname');
    $("#wrapper > #right2-chg").attr('id','right2').fadeIn(3000);
    $("#wrapper > #left-surname").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".click").hide();
});

});
```

But:

1. It seems not best solution. How can I write code more readable.
2. how to move bottom divs to freed space after moving another divs? You can see  this issue with #left-phone.(I think the same as in my code, but it produce a lot of code rows)

Comment: In my opinion I have unique divs so that's why I use id's.

Comment: I think I understood yours idea, I will try...

Answer (score 0):

I changed code:

```
   ([http://jsfiddle.net/dimaomni/SThaQ/8/][1])
```

It works. thanks